# appending php into a div and maintaining the current css

Tags: php, jquery

Okay.. this is the file lo_add.php:

```
<div class="rowElem">
    <label>Item <? echo $i ?>:</label>
    <div class="formRight searchDrop">
        <select name="lo_item[]" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Choose an Item">
            <option value=""></option>
            <? $item_query = mysql_query("select id,code,title,price from items where domain_id='$domain_id' order by code");
            while ($items = mysql_fetch_array($item_query)) { ?>
                <option value="<? echo $items["id"] ?>"><? echo $items["code"]." - ".$items["title"]." - RM".$items["price"] ?></option>
            <? } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <label>Delivery Address :</label>
    <div class="formRight searchDrop">
        <select name="lo_site[]" class="chzn-select" data-placeholder="Choose a Delivery Address">
            <option value=""></option>
                <? $site_query = mysql_query("select id,name from sites where domain_id='$domain_id' order by name");
                while ($sites = mysql_fetch_array($site_query)) { ?>
                    <option value="<? echo $sites["id"] ?>"><? echo $sites["name"] ?></option>
                <? } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="fix"></div>
    <label>Quantity:<span class="req">*</span></label>
    <div class="formRight onlyNums">
        <input type="text" name="lo_quantity[]" id="lo_quantity[]"/>
    </div>
    <div class="fix"></div>
</div>
```

And this is the html file that calls the css and what have you in the beginning:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<title>Mecacom Technologies&reg; Maintenance System &copy; 2012</title>

<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/wizards/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#addElement').click(function() {
    var data = '';
    $.get('/ajax/lo_add.php', data, function(response){
      $('#hello').append(response);
    });
  });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="content" id="container">
        <div class="title"><h5>Record New Local Order</h5></div>

        <form action="<? echo $PHP_SELF ?>?add=1" id="valid" class="mainForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="widget">
                    <div class="head"><h5 class="iLocked2">New Local Order Credentials</h5></div>

                    <div class="rowElem noborder">
                        <label>Order ID:<span class="req">*</span></label>
                        <div class="formRight">
                            <input type="text" class="validate[required]" name="order_id" id="order_id"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fix"></div>
                   </div>

                    <div class="rowElem noborder">
                        <label>Order Date:<span class="req">*</span></label>
                        <div class="formRight">
                            <input type="text" name="order_date" class="datepicker validate[required]" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="fix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="hello"></div>

                    <div class="fix"></div>
                    <a href="#" id="addElement">Click To Append More Item</a>
                    <input type="submit" value="Next" class="greyishBtn submitForm" />
                    <div class="fix"><input type="hidden" name="addnow" value="1" /></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

*sigh* .. quite a handful ... How do you think that the css aren't being rendered correctly after the jquery append?

Comment: What does your CSS look like?

Comment: Jocelyn: the css being drawn from a file using <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> it's kinda huge to include it here .. but thing is ... it was rendered perfectly until the new appended element rendering plainly

Comment: Nothing to do with jquery, ajax or php. What we need is the final HTML and the final CSS. Or at least the relevant parts.

Comment: right .. here's the link http://meca-moe.homeip.net and enter the following credentials as login/password - test/test .. click through Local Order --> Record New Local Order .. and then try clicking on "Click To Append More Item" and see how distorted the css gonna be ... hope this helps instead of plunging in all codes unnecessarily in here :-) .. thanx

Comment: Ug, sorry, you need to keep it in SO. What is the class heirarchy for those elements and what is the CSS???

Comment: okay .. and how am I to paste it in here? with the previous original form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from your live test page that you are using [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to process the dropdowns and jQuery [validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) to validate the quantity field.

The first thing is to make sure you call `chosen()` on the newly created dropdowns. This has to be called for new elements, because Chosen doesn't only rely on CSS, but changes the entire HTML structure of the dropdowns. So add this line, following your append,

```
$(".chzn-select").chosen()
```

Second is to make sure you validate the newly created quantity textfields by calling `validate()` on them, or re-calling whatever javascript you called to initialize the validate plugin.

Comment: darsky, you mean I need add <javascript> in every append .. yes?

Comment: I meant to add this line of code right after the append code like `$('#hello').append(response); $(".chzn-select").chosen();`

Comment: owh .. sorry .. should've told in here that I've done that .. thanx ya darksky!